# Stroke width, or line material in three-globe

Tags: three.js

Just trying to up the stroke width a little on the country polygons for [three-globe](https://github.com/vasturiano/three-globe).

There doesn't appear to be a helper function for this material or any settings beyond color.

I had the bright idea of looping through all the children of the globe object, very crude but:

```
for (let i in Globe.children[0].children[4].children){
    const child = Globe.children[0].children[4].children[i];
    child.children[1].material.linewidth = 3;
    child.children[1].material.color = new THREE.Color('rgba(255,255,255,1)');
}
```

This appears to have no effect on the line width. It does, however, successfully change the color, so I think I'm close, though I really hope there's a better way than this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to inform you that the `.linewidth` property is very poorly supported due to OpenGL limitations. You can see an explanation in the [LineBasicMaterial.linewidth documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mathut#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial.linewidth)

> Due to limitations of the OpenGL Core Profile with the WebGL renderer on most platforms linewidth will always be 1 regardless of the set value.

You'll run into this issue if you're using `THREE.Line` or `THREE.LineSegments`. However, there is an alternative you could use with [`THREE.Line2`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/lines/Line2.js), which circumvents the limitation by drawing lots of instanced `gl.TRIANGLES` instead of `gl.LINE`. You can see it in action [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lines_fat). In fact, there are [3 demos of fat lines](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fat), each one with a slightly different implementation. You would then have to substitute the outlines of the country with your own fat lines.